# A shorter type constraint for F#

Tags: f#, type-constraints

I'm practicing with F# and I've though of implementing a type-constrained compare function for F#. In C#, it's implemented by this

```cs
// in C#
static int cmp<T>(T x, T y) where T: System.IComparable<T>
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
}
```

However, in F#, the best way I've come up is this.

```
(* in F# *)
let cmp (x: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) (y: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) 
    = x.CompareTo(y)
```

I tried the one below but it didn't work

```
let cmp (x: 'a) (y: 'a) when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable
    = x.CompareTo(y)
```

Is my working F# sample the shortest way or is there another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another (cleaner, IMO) way to implement this is by adding an explicit generic type parameter to the function, like this:

```
let cmp<'T when 'T :> System.IComparable<'T>> (x : 'T) (y : 'T) =
    x.CompareTo y
```

Comment: This is better. The use of `<'T when 'T :> System.IComparable<'T>>` near function `cmp` sends a clear signal on the constraint of `'T` for the parameters `x` and `y`.

Comment: Another slight variation `let cmp<'T when 'T :> 'T System.IComparable> (x : 'T) (y : 'T) = x.CompareTo y`. I'm personally not found of nested `<>`.

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound Your variation uses the older OCaml-style syntax. There's nothing wrong with it, but IIRC it's not considered "canonical" F# style. For anything other than `list` and a few other built-in types, I'd recommend using the notation I used -- it's a much more intuitive syntax for C# developers who're just learning F#. Some people prefer to add add spaces to avoid putting the angle-brackets together, like this: `cmp< 'T when 'T :> System.IComparable<'T> >`.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the historical background.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it. I was browsing through the examples in MSDN's F# [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233203.aspx) and at the thrid from the last example, I found this

```
let inline add(value1 : ^T when ^T : (static member (+) : ^T * ^T -> ^T), value2: ^T) =
    value1 + value2
```

I notice that constraint for `^T` in `value1` is used in `value2`, so I change my `cmp` function to this

```
let cmp (x: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) (y: 'a) = x.CompareTo(y)
```

I ran through the `fsi` and got the same type signature

```
> let cmp (x: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) (y: 'a) = x.CompareTo(y);;

val cmp : 'a -> 'a -> int when 'a :> System.IComparable<'a>

> let cmp (x: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) (y: 'a when 'a :> 'a System.IComparable) = x.CompareTo(y);;

val cmp : 'a -> 'a -> int when 'a :> System.IComparable<'a>
```